# Ler json com a biblioteca GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Como faço para ler este código com a biblioteca GSON?

```
{
    "profissao": {
        "jornalista": [
            "escritor",
            "legal",
            "fotografo"
        ],
        "programador": [
          "focado",
          "exatas",
          "articulado"
       ],
       "maquinista": [
          "senai",
          "mecanico",
          "articulado"
      ]    
   }
}
```

Comment: Você queria ler somente ou passar esse conteudo para uma classe?

Comment: passar para uma classe seria melhor !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando [HasMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) com [coleção de `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) dá para trabalhar com os dados [json](/questions/tagged/json) que tem o `layout` de **chave** e **valor**, ***exemplo básico***:

***Código:***

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

Gson gson = new Gson();

try (Reader reader = new FileReader("c:\\Temp\\arquivo.json"))
{
    Type listType =
           new TypeToken<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>>>(){}.getType();
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>> c = gson.fromJson(reader, listType);
    HashMap<String, List<String>> get = c.get("profissao");
    Set<String> items =  get.keySet();
    for(String item: items){
        System.out.println(item);
        System.out.println(get.get(item));
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
    }    
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{    
}
```

***Saída:***

```
run:
jornalista
[escritor, legal, fotografo]
-----------------------
maquinista
[senai, mecanico, articulado]
-----------------------
programador
[focado, exatas, articulado]
-----------------------
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Class HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
- [Interface List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [GSON to deserialise array of name/value pairs <sup>SOEn</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033366/gson-to-deserialise-array-of-name-value-pairs)
- [Post Processing on Gson Deserialization](https://medium.com/@elye.project/post-processing-on-gson-deserialization-26ce5790137d)
- [Gson Map Key Pair to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986269/gson-map-key-pair-to-json)
- [Class KeyPair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPair.html)
- [google-gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: Voce consegue mostrar seu import?

Comment: @RodrigoGabriel editado, e foram colocados.

Comment: Certinho cara muito obrigado!

Comment: Tem as setas que dão pontuação pra cima positivo pra baixo negativo e também pode aceitar a resposta como solução que é abaixo das setas um check.

Comment: e caso eu quero mostrar separadamente as caracteristicas de cada profissao? tipo jornalista \n escritor \n legal \n fotografo

Comment: é só fazer um for de `get.get(item)` tipo `for(string ic: get.get(item))` e dentro desse for imprimir o `ic` !

Comment: nice deu certo consegui fazer dessa maneira tbm

Answer (score -1):

```java
package Application;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // referência:
        // https://mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        try (Reader reader = new FileReader(
                "C:\\temp\\data.json");) {

            JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonElement.class);

            String jsonString = gson.toJson(json);

            System.out.println(jsonString);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```