# Ler json com gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Gostaria de ler o JSON abaixo com GSON, colocar cada linha em um POJO e adicionar em um `ArrayList`. Mas não estou conseguindo ler o JSON.

```
{"user_id":"K4cXASVRZHM6l_t0l_kBzQ","name":"Rob","review_count":238,"friends":"7VQ46TLFWcJ9NC-Sf9r0cQ, GEbyCpz3QmMh23kYcFS_sg, QDFF2MmjuQpeBGTf4yCQZg, Wz0ZiO-tD-QlGBNlX4JZng, 5bfzMNW7lrLXeWB5YG375g"}

{"user_id":"8AUGRc11vpsRtWAltI4jBA","name":"Emily","review_count":29, "friends":"kIkVDAxrvuLmHw86QWG-YQ, eXYhS1UyJc_Y70kJj6yl_A, BeoIUVPMCSYom7KANYQ0ng, R_lyLZuewPOJYH3k8oAhPw, ujY7b27NQ6pFcUuLYYK9BA, JNh4hmFuC40QhQvFToLeQw, 2wWMgBlRmUvli3MBRTlISA"}

{"user_id":"07MFiMnhPoTpQCNYcqGyBQ","name":"Eddie","review_count":24, "friends":"wTvvYzGrmeQYkZ1QDTRi0w, OIMBD_tc_Bu2Ro1UdaDYsw, zZyF0GPjjb5qp63ebUyHcw, 3b1zZxhzQc7lIdFk6fJDxQ, o0eSwQKB04e3SxwqIfhexA, n5MRQzcvCVK2uR43LWxkoQ, xJprckZNAp9v0Vzd-7km7g"}
```

Tentei assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("yelp_academic_dataset_user.json"));

    List<NoUsuario> data = gson.fromJson(reader, NoUsuario);
}
```

Comment: Tente postar o que você já tentou fazer, para que assim possamos melhor te ajudar, desta forma a pergunta fica muito ampla.

Comment: Possível duplicata de: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232797/ler-json-com-a-biblioteca-gson

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ler json com a biblioteca GSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232797/ler-json-com-a-biblioteca-gson)

Comment: Tentei pelo que mandaram como possível duplicata mas não consegui. Acho que o meu jeito de fazer o fromJson está errado. Como vcs fariam?

Comment: Cintia, tenta adicionar o código que já fez, daí vemos onde pode estar errando ;)

Comment: Tentei com List[NoUsuario], mas não vai

Comment: Qual exceção você está recebendo? Edite sua pergunta e coloque-a lá.

Comment: Você precisa colocar o código da sua classe `NoUsuario` para analisarmos também.